# Help! How to cement plaster outer wall. If gap between the two walls are 1 feet only?

Tags: civil-engineering, masonry, reinforcement

[House Plan Image]

[image: house plan image]

My neighbor is not allowing us to wall plaster of the side outer wall.(Facing Neighbor side) How can I plaster the outer wall, which has a gap of 1 feet between our wall and neighbor enemy's wall.

[Similar side wall with only bricks]

[image: Similar side wall with only bricks]

Please suggest the best technique to do side outer wall plastering.
Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how wide your wall is. But there are pumps with small flexible hoses of 20 feet long. You can use a 20 foot pipe or handle and reach the spray nuzzle to the right space.

Here is a link to one manufacturer, [concrete pump.](https://www.graco.com/us/en/contractor/product/24t834-toughtek-m680a.html)

Comment: In this case using the spray machine, there are chances of the cement spray to get splashed to the neighbors house right?

Comment: An experienced mason knows what pressure and what nuzzle with what funnel to use to keep the cement from spraying randomly. I have had a similar Jobsite in California with a litigious neighbor, we covered everything but the wall with plastic sheets, even the tree branches. Also, the cement journeymen load a long-handled trawl with a bit of cement and trawl it on the hard to reach spots.

Comment: For the OP's benefit. Depending on the length of the wall & the height of the roof, spraying from the roof may be an option. To avoid getting spray on the neighbor's wall heavy sheets of plastic, or similar, weighted at the bottom & supported by on overhang from the roof could be considered.

Comment: Sure, the height of the wall to be plastered is 23 feet width is 1 feet.. so you say we can have a pipe spray machine to do plastering?

Comment: 23 feet height and 1 feet width.  ||<--1 feet-->|| is the Gap between two walls.